# Bad formatting of search result with MediaWiki 1.26.3

Tags: mediawiki

I just upgraded my company's internal wiki and now the search results appear badly formatted.

The image below shows the `H2` containing the text `Page text matches` on the right of the page, below the `Page title matches`. When the page shrinks or expands the search results move to the left below the title matches (as in the image) or to the right below the `Page text matches` text. The `Page text matches` text always stays up there and becomes invisible if the page shrinks too much.

Is it a problem with MediaWiki 1.26.3?

Did I mess something up during the upgrade?

How do I fix it?

[image]

```
MediaWiki  1.26.3
PHP        5.5.35
MySQL      5.5.48-37.8
ICU        4.2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a regression of the 1.26.

Here is the ticket: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T122499

Here is the workaround:

1. Go to `http://your.wiki.url/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Common.css`
2. Add the following code:

   `.mw-search-results {
        float: none;
   }`